# Is there any way to change the status bar color via Flutter in a PWA?

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

Is there any way to change the status bar color via Flutter Web in an installed PWA?

[image: pwa]

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the value for `theme-color`. The default color is defined in your `web/manifest.json` file.

You could also set it, for example to white for your light-theme and to black for your dark-theme, by adding following lines to your `web/index.html`:

```html
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="#FFFFFF">
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"  content="#000000">
```

You could also change it dynamically via `dart:js` by adding a script to your `web/index.html`:

```html
<script>
  function setMetaThemeColor(color) {
      document.querySelector('meta[name="theme-color"]').setAttribute("content", color);
    }
</script>
```

Then call it via `dart:js`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:js' as js;

extension ColorString on Color {
  String toHexString() {
    return '#${(value & 0xFFFFFF).toRadixString(16).padLeft(6, '0').toUpperCase()}';
  }
}

void setMetaThemeColor(Color color) {
  js.context.callMethod("setMetaThemeColor", [color.toHexString()]);
}
```