# How to specify flutterweb-theme for Safari header color

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I know that the safari web header uses the following code to set it's color.

```
<meta id="flutterweb-theme" name="theme-color" content="#2196f3">
```

(results pictured below)
[image: picture of safari web header]

however, I can't find anywhere to specify what this color is in the flutter docs or anywhere else. Is there somewhere that shows where I can manually set this without a hacky regex on posting to live?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71474380/1399597